# codeigniter, htaccess force https except one url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I try to force all urls to https except one url. so far no success. Anyone knows what is wrong with my htaccess or codeignter?

*Url test 1:*

http://hub-dev-1.andatech.com.au/utility/mandrills/email_bounced_back

Should stays as

http://hub-dev-1.andatech.com.au/utility/mandrills/email_bounced_back

*Url test 2:*

http://hub-dev-1.andatech.com.au/controller/method

I use this tool to test htaccess: http://htaccess.mwl.be/

Here is my htaccess

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/utility/mandrills/email_bounced_back
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(assets|test)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Test on http://htaccess.mwl.be, working.

Test on browser,
http://hub-dev-1.andatech.com.au/utility/mandrills/email_bounced_back redirects to 
https://hub-dev-1.andatech.com.au/utility/mandrills/email_bounced_back

apache conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin test@test.com
  ServerName hub-dev-1.andatech.com.au
  ServerAlias www.hub-dev-1.andatech.com.au
  DocumentRoot /home/thehub/public_html
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

  <Directory /home/thehub/public_html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    # Hak apache 2.2
    # Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    # Hak apache 2.4
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

ssl apache conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAdmin test@test.com
  ServerName hub-dev-1.andatech.com.au
  ServerAlias www.hub-dev-1.andatech.com.au
  DocumentRoot /home/thehub/public_html
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

  <Directory /home/thehub/public_html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    # Hak apache 2.2
    # Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    # Hak apache 2.4
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/hub-dev-1.andatech.com.au/fullchain.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/hub-dev-1.andatech.com.au/privkey.pem
  Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: it does get `index.php` in the next round. Maybe `RewriteRule ^/?index\.php - [L]` as a top rule would solve this.

Comment: exactly, the second rule is prepending index.php, then it (internally) goes back to the top of rewrite pipeline and in second pass it is not caught by `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/utility/mandrills/email_bounced_back` (because of index,php) and is therefore rewritten to https.

Comment: you could for example just remove `^` from `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/utility/mandrills/email_bounced_back`

Comment: Sorry, what is the 2nd pass? I thought http://hub-dev-1.andatech.com.au/utility/mandrills/email_bounced_back fails the first rewriterule, then able to meet the 2nd rewrite rule. which is the index.php. The last rewriterule has [PT,L], so that is the final. no.....?

Comment: No: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l